# Specifying non-default port for Homebrew Postgres server

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I have installed Postgres using Homebrew on macOS. I can start a Postgres server which listens to the default port 5432 using the command `brew services start postgres`, but I want it to use a different port.

Using my Homebrew Postgres installation, how can I start a Postgres server which listens to another port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `pg_ctl` is installed (it should be - but you can check with `which pg_ctl`) you can use it to specify the port when starting your Postgres server:

```
pg_ctl -o "-p 5433" start
```

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html)

Comment: I had to change this to `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -o "-p 5433" start`, but then it worked for me, thanks.

Comment: for homebrew `pg_ctl -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgres -o "-p 5433" start`

Answer (score 8):

For a persistent fix you can alter the configuration files:

**1. Determine where brew installed Postgres**

`brew info postgresql@<your_version>`

The location on my machine was `/usr/local/var/postgresql@14/postgresql.conf`

**2. Navigate there and open postgresql.conf**

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = 'localhost' # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5555             # (change requires restart)
```

You can then set the port and address before restarting postgresql.

**3. Restart postgresql**

`brew services restart postgresql`

Comment: I've followed this instruction, but the homebrew postgresql service does not seem to be affected by changes to the postgresql.conf file. (There was only a sample one in the appropriate `share` folder, so I copied it as postgresql.conf in the same folder and uncommented the necessary lines.)

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled postgresql with homebrew. The correct location to edit postgresql.conf is actually in /usr/local/var/postgresql@14/postgresql.conf on my installation and machine. I've updated my answer to reflect this. You may also want to look into whether you used sudo to install postgres as this may affect the installation location (although I have not yet tested to confirm)

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction. I'm running apple silicon, so for me the location was /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14/postgresql.conf. Thanks.

Comment: This works for me. But, you need to check the correct postgresql directory - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/how-do-i-find-postgresqls-data-directory